# How to update data in appengine datastore programmatically?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I just started to use `appengine datastore` and looking for a way to update the data while fetching it. Here is the code:

```
DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
Query q = new Query("Users").addFilter("value", Query.FilterOperator.EQUAL, 1);
PreparedQuery pq = datastore.prepare(q);
    if(pq!=null) {

        for (com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Entity result : pq.asIterable()) {
            nodeID = result.getProperty("nodeId").toString();
            result.setProperty("value",0);
            datastore.put(result);
            break;

        }
    }
```

It's fetching the data but not able to update the `value` field in `datastore`. What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: In what way is it "not able to update the `value` field in `datastore`"?

Comment: I used `result.setproperty("value",0);`

Comment: How do you know it is not working?

Comment: I can see datastore data in "localhost:8080/_ah/api/explorer"

Comment: Do you mean the local datastore viewer?  What you're seeing may be eventual consistency, so what happens if you do a `datastore.get(key)` on the entity after you `put()` it? That will tell you for sure if it's working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your above code and it worked fine for me.

```
DatastoreService datastore =  DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
Query q = new Query("Users").addFilter("value", Query.FilterOperator.EQUAL, 1);
PreparedQuery pq = datastore.prepare(q);
if(pq!=null) {

    for (com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Entity result : pq.asIterable()) {
        nodeID = result.getProperty("nodeId").toString();
        result.setProperty("value",0);
        datastore.put(result);
        break;

    }
}
```